# Using url_for between two applications

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I liked a lot of the conventions the [Overholt example](http://mattupstate.com/python/2013/06/26/how-i-structure-my-flask-applications.html) used, but ran into a specific problem.

I have two apps set up using the DispatcherMiddleware object from werkzeug.wsgi:

```
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
from myapp import api, frontend

application = DispatcherMiddleware(frontend.create_app(), {
    '/api': api.create_app()
})
```

This works great; the end points are all there.  Inspecting `application.app.url_map` shows the mappings for frontend, and `application.mounts['/api'].url_map` shows the mappings for api correctly.

The problem I'm running into is I'd like to use `url_for()` in my frontend templates for methods in api, but haven't found a way to make that work.  Hardcoding the URL paths works, but will cause problems later if I want to move things around.

Comment: Apps run through a dispatcher are isolated from each other.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a new route to your back-end, say `/api/route-map` which spits out a map (dictionary/JSON) of the routes (you can use `url_for` to generate the map) and hit this route from your front-end to get the dynamic route map, which you can use through out your front-end templates with your custom jinja2 function (which you can create as shown below).

```
def api_url_for(route_fn_string):
    """
    This is just boilerplate code. Please do some checking here.
    '"""
    return route_map[route_fn_string]


app.jinja_env.globals.update(api_url_for=api_url_for)
```

Now you can do `{{api_url_for('update')}}` in your jinja2 template to get its actual route.

If you're putting both the apps on the same server, then you can simply share the route map as a global or through a getter function.